# Get WebFacing library list in Java

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jtopen

I have a `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400` object for a WebFacing connection in my application. On the COBOL side, some libraries are added to the library list at the beginning of the program. How do I retrieve them in Java from my AS400 object?

Comment: Please elaborate.  Are you trying to determine the library list that was changed after calling the COBOL program from a com.ibm.as400.access.ProgramCall (or CommandCall)?  Or do you need to set your library list so that you can safely call the COBOL program?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a [job](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/info/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/Job.html) object then call get library list method [getUserLibraryList](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/info/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/Job.html#getUserLibraryList())